# How to increment css values in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

In Chrome Developer tools say I inspect an element such as img. How can I increment the value of an css property such as top or left from within the Tools when I inspect?

I saw a developer do this in a screencast.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the developer tools-> elements. now you can see the codes for the page. select the code( or double click on the code) and change the value. after changing the value hit enter. your page will refresh and the new value will be reflected.